# database search result giving Trying to get property of non-object error on $result

Tags: php, mysql

when I run the search script I'm getting the following error
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 32
Why is it telling me it is not an object? It obviously gives a similar error on line 47.
I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

```
7<?php
8  // create short variable names
9  $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
10  $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
11
12 if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
13    echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
14     exit;
15 }
16
17  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
18    $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
19    $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
20  }
21
22  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'printfactory0', '*********', 'printfactory');
23
24  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
25     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
26     exit;
27  }
28
29  $query = "select * from printfactory where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
30  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
31
32  $num_results = $result->num_rows;
33
34  echo "<p>Number of products found: ".$num_results."</p>";
35
36  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
37     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
38     echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Product Name: ";
39     echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['ProductName']));
40     echo "</strong><br />Product Description: ";
41     echo stripslashes($row['Product_Description']);
42     echo "<br />Price: ";
43     echo stripslashes($row['Unit_Price']);
44     echo "</p>";
45  }
46
47  $result->free();
48  $db->close();
49
50?>
```

Comment: You're not doing any error checking or you'd know that there was something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your query failed. You need to check your return value, and inspect the error message.

```
if( ! $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) ) {
    die(mysqli_error($db));
}
```

**ABC**: **A**lways **B**e **C**hecking [your return values]

Comment: Thank you. I will check as soon as I can. Sorry but I'm quite new to coding

Comment: ok, I had time to check for the error and it turns out that in line 29 i put the name of the database instead of the name of the table where the search must be done. Thanks @Sammitch. Very helpful. I tried to vote the comment up but because of my lack of reputation it wont let me.